Azure AKS with Managed Identity can not write to Application Insights
We have a Kubernets app that is authenticated with "Managed Identity". All works fine.
Now we like to add "Application Insights" as Java agent with "LOCAL AUTHENTICATION" disabled for "Application Insights". So the "Managed Identity" should authenticate.
When we switch on "LOCAL AUTHENTICATION" then it works. But we do not like to do it that way.
Is this possible?
Cheers T

Yes, if you have your managed identities setup in AKS, you can disable "Local Authentication" in order to use it with java agent. Here is the azure docs on how to configure it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-ad-authentication?tabs=java#system-assigned-managed-identity. Please ping me if you have any other questions.

Thanks for your help. This was the correct answer. I added the evn variable: "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING" and "Authorization=AAD;ClientId=..." Then the Infrastructure guy had to give some right and it worked. Thanks for your help!
